# Svelte each loops are overlapping

Tags: html, svelte, sveltekit

I am developing in the newest version of SvelteKit and I have one page (`routes/index/+page.svelte`) where the problem is caused to a component (`lib/components/Header.svelte`) that appears in every page (`+layout.svelte`).

```html
<!-- lib/components/Header.svelte --<

<header>
  <nav>
    <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-click-events-have-key-events -->
    <div id="header__nav__toggle">
      <input type="checkbox" on:click={openMenu}/>
      {#if routeId == "/about"}
        <span style="background-color: var(--foreground--primary)"></span>
        <span style="background-color: var(--foreground--primary)"></span>
        <span style="background-color: var(--foreground--primary)"></span>
      {:else}
        <span style="background-color: var(--highlight)"></span>
        <span style="background-color: var(--highlight)"></span>
        <span style="background-color: var(--highlight)"></span>
      {/if}
      <ul id="menu">
        {#each routes as {title, href}}
          {#if $page.url.pathname.startsWith("/audio/") || $page.url.pathname.startsWith("/video/")}
            <li {title}><a href={href} on:click={openPage} on:mouseover={pageLinkHover} on:focus={pageLinkHover} on:mouseleave={pageLinkLeave} style="color: var(--foreground--secondary); box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);">{title}</a></li>
          {:else}
            <li {title}><a href={href} on:click={openPage} on:mouseover={pageLinkHover} on:focus={pageLinkHover} on:mouseleave={pageLinkLeave} style="color: var(--foreground--primary)">{title}</a></li>
          {/if}
        {/each}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

```html
<!-- routes/index/+page.svelte -->

<script lang="ts">
    import Head from "$lib/components/Head.svelte"
  import { routes } from '$lib/helpers/routes';
    import { shuffleArray } from "$lib/helpers/shuffleArray"
  export let data
  routes.push(...data.audioFiles, ...data.videoFiles)
  const random = shuffleArray(routes)
</script>

<article class="index">
  <div class="index__list-container">
    <ul class="index__list">
      {#each random as {title, href}}
        <li class="index__list__item" {title}><a class="index__list__item__anchor" href={href}>{title}</a></li>
      {/each}
    </ul>
  </div>
</article>
```

The problem is that when I visit `/index`, all of the links in `.index__list` will appear in the `Header` component's links `#menu`; I've already tried to change then names of `title` and `href` to so that they're both unique across files.

Comment: Hi @concatenations7, may I know what is inside `random`?

Comment: @AngYC `random` is a total of 3 arrays shuffled by a basic function. I've updated `+page.svelte` to show how it's created and I've confirmed that the random function is not the cause of the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies between your [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) on `routes` constant:

```js
routes.push(...data.audioFiles, ...data.videoFiles)
```

I am assuming `routes` is an array of links that contains `title` and `href`. However, when you perform `.push`, it is modifying that array in-place which modified the value which you thought is a constant.

Once you do that, `routes` array that is being referred anywhere in the code will contain the `data.audioFiles` and `data.videoFiles` as well, thus causing the confusion that you have seen.

An alternative approach is to use [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) which creates a copy of the original array and merge with whatever array you have:

```js
const newRoutes = routes.concat(data.audioFiles, data.videoFiles);
const random = shuffleArray(newRoutes);
```

Comment: `concat` accepts any number of arrays, so this could be simplified to `routes.concat(data.audioFiles, data.videoFiles);`

Comment: Hi @H.B., thanks for letting me know! I always forgot about this, modified the answer :)